# PDO expecption error while adding class to the block with sql server

Tags: blocks

> "PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'css_class'.: UPDATE block SET
>   [css_class]=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE ([module] =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND ([delta] =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( ) in block_class_form_submit()
>   (line 99 of .....\sites\all\modules\block_class\block_class.module)."

Adding class to the block using block class module. while adding class to the block throwing pdo exception error coming. Please any one resolve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of install one module for this, you can just use the ID for that block and create your custom css.

Example:

```
div#block-block-10{
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

I think that could solve your problem